# Django Models, on delete set pk

Tags: python, django

This is my models:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    indirizzo = models.CharField(max_length=40)


class Appo(models.Model):
    appo = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, default=1,related_name='appocli')
```

now, if I delete a Customer I need SQL set in Appo models a specific PK for customer Foreign Key. For example 1.

Something like: on delete set 1

Please help

Comment: so on delete, you want to store customer's primary key to the Appo model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`SET_DEFAULT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET_NULL) to set your foreign key to a default value

```
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=1)
```